# Highcharts x-axis label automatic grouping

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts to display data for over a period of one month so it it could be displaying anywhere form 1 data point to 31 data points (I'm using the jQuery Datepicker widget to select dates). My problem is with the x-Axis. When viewing between 2 and 7 data points the x-axis is automatically trying to adjust itself which works fine the more data points are being rendered but when there are less as previously mentioned there are problems.

I have captured some screenshots showing my perdicament as well as created a JSFiddle. I do have a specific size that I need to fit the chart in and I have used the same size in the JSfiddle.

What I would like ideally is for the x-axis to start on the first of the month (or at the lest NOT start on the end of the previous month) and avoid overlapping issues. I'm hoping it's a setting that I'm overlooking that controls how highcharts "automatically" calculates what is displayed on the x-axis and it's interval. I know there is a tick-interval setting but I've not had any luck with that in my situation.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7hIp.png

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/sgKcB/

Here is the highcharts code:

```
 $('.chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %e, '%y", this.value);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var date = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b><br />';
            return date + this.y;
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

Assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What should I choose in datepicker, to see that issue as in your images? Also, two things: set datetime xAxis, and use dateTimeLabelFormats instead of formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/sgKcB/26/

Comment: I've updated some of the code in my fiddle example to better simulate the scenario. Selecting the 17th through the 27th should result in  what I'm experiencing with the x-axis displaying the end of the previous month first. That has been really throwing off my client. However, you're solution of using 'datetime' and 'dateTimeLabelFormats' appears to be the exact fix that I need (I included it in the fiddle but commented it out for the purpose of the example). If you post that as an answer I will accept it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution seems to be `datetime` xAxis and `dateTimeLabelFormats` option for Highcharts. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/sgKcB/26

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: "%b %e, '%y",
            week: "%b %e, '%y"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you! Another part of my problem is I was using the highstocks library and not highcharts. Apparently that made a difference too. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPositioner parameter, which allows your own function. You can calculate and return correct order of your ticks.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: I'm using a Date.UTC object to determine the x-axis. Would that be an issue?